# inftyreader ocrparams coordinates conversion to pdf coordinates

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am very impressed with inftyreader about generation of iml and plan to buy personal license in the near future. I am concerned about ocrparams coordinates generated in iml mapped to PDF coordinates.

For Example sample iml:

```
<p style="Text" newline="1" ocrparam="433,1475,1458,1568,0">
    <mblock>
        <munit cost="1" ocrparam="433,1475,483,1558,0">F</munit><munit cost="85" ocrparam="500,1500,558,1567,0">o</munit>
        <munit entity="1" cost="34" ocrparam="575,1508,607,1568,0">llcorner</munit>
        <munit cost="0" ocrparam="608,1508,625,1559,0">l</munit><munit entity="1" cost="20" ocrparam="642,1508,675,1558,0">ulcorner</munit>
        <munit cost="8" ocrparam="683,1492,717,1567,0">t</munit><munit cost="0" ocrparam="725,1500,783,1567,0">e</munit>
        <munit cost="0" ocrparam="792,1500,850,1567,0">e</munit><munit cost="0" ocrparam="867,1500,917,1558,0">n</munit>
        <munit cost="8" ocrparam="933,1492,967,1567,0">t</munit><munit italic="1" cost="35" ocrparam="975,1475,996,1559,0">l</munit>
        <munit entity="1" cost="8" ocrparam="997,1500,1025,1559,0">neg</munit><munit cost="0" ocrparam="1083,1475,1133,1567,0">E</munit>
        <munit cost="0" ocrparam="1150,1475,1217,1567,0">d</munit><munit cost="20" ocrparam="1233,1483,1242,1558,0">i</munit>
        <munit cost="6" ocrparam="1258,1492,1292,1567,0">t</munit><munit cost="20" ocrparam="1308,1508,1317,1558,0">|</munit>
        <munit cost="0" ocrparam="1333,1500,1392,1567,0">0</munit><munit cost="26" ocrparam="1408,1508,1429,1559,0">l</munit>
        <munit entity="1" cost="14" ocrparam="1430,1500,1458,1559,0">neg</munit>
    </mblock>
    <char ocrparam="1308,1475,1317,1492,0" cost="25">singleendquartation</char>
</p>
```

Please analyze how to map these ocrparam to pdf coordinates.

Comment: Why the pdfbox and itext labels?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I guess because they have become very common brand names for anything related to PDF in software development, sort of like "kodak" (in some languages) is used for all brands of photo cameras, or "bic" and "sharpie" for all brands of pens. Still doesn't make it ok though. I edited them away.

Comment: Also: hi! It's good to see that a core contributor of our dear friends of PDFBox is also keeping an eye on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse hello too :-) My question was sortof rhetorical, I always hope that somebody who did that in a question will come up with some amazing never-heard-before explanation, but it never happens LOL

Comment: @TilmanHausherr   Please How to map the coordinates using itext and pdfbox 2.0.7

Comment: pdfbox does not process the xml shown. You'd have to know in what units these coordinates are, and where the origin is. (bottom left or top left). In PDF, the user space unit is (usually) 1/72 inch.